# Find and Replace Multiple Values and update in another column

Tags: excel, vba

```
 sub ()
   for i = 3 to 6
   worksheets("sheet1").range("a2:a35").select

   selection.replace what:=cells(i,3).value,replacement:=cells(i,4).value,
   lookat:xlpart,searchorder:=xlByRows,matchcase:=False

   Next

   Worksheets("sheet1").cells(1,1).select

 end sub
```

What if the value to be replaced is in another column? For example, I still want the range of value to be found in column "A" but then replace the value in "column B" of the same row. How would the code change?

Comment: An example or two might help here - it's not clear exactly what you want to change.

Comment: if column A has aplle 123 should replace column b value as laptop where b column already has some text values

Comment: I'm still not following.  Example "before" and "after" data would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Find` method and read row numbers from the found results (`Row` property). You can use that information to refer to cell in the column you need to change.